# Reserving physical memory using flattened device tree

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, device-tree

I have a beagle bone which has 256Mb of memory which has the dtb file.

```
memory{
        device_type = "memory";
        reg = <0x80000000 0x10000000>;
     };
```

I expect the following change to reduce the available physical memory by 1Mb which i plan to access using io_pfn_page_range() in my driver.

```
memory{
        device_type = "memory";
        reg = <0x80000000 0x0FF00000>;
     };
```

But even after the change the /proc/meminfo does not reflect the change. Am i missing something. Thanks in advance.

Rakesh

Comment: Check if U-Boot (or whatever bootloader) is building and providing ATAGs.  Check the kernel configuration if ATAGs are allowed to augment the Device Tree, i.e. *""Support for the traditional ATAGS boot data passing"* and *"Supplement the appended DTB with traditional ATAG information"*.  Check the kernel command line.

Comment: Have you tried the same with any of the kernel command line options?

Comment: Make sure u-boot does not overwrite your changes. u-boot is smart enough to know the total amount of memory in the system and will automagically modify the device tree passed to the kernel. If you hand edited the device tree those changes will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

The bootargs passed through uEnv.txt using mem=255M does the required change. The dtb change is not respected though.

Answer (score 0):

devices-tree(dts) changes will be over written by uboot

***Option1:***

```
Add mem=255M , in bootargs
Eg: setenv bootargs 'root=/dev/ram rw console=ttyS0,115200 mem=255M
```

***Option2:***

```
setenv bootm_size 0xFF00000
```